# Global shiny variables in Markdown document

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm using shiny widgets in an R Markdown document. When creating shiny apps previously (not within a Markdown context), I was able to make large static datasets global variables that only got loaded once. I am now trying to do something similar but within a Markdown document.

I have a list of over 5000 items in a CSV file. I am going to pull one at random each day and then use it in the program to generate some information and plots. I would like the random item to be the same for each person every day, and this is where I am getting stuck. I know how to get it to work if it is just a new random item for each session, but I'm not sure how to make it the same for each session.

````
---
#title: "Daily Random Thing"
#author: "Tyler Beason"
#date: "Wednesday, June 24, 2015"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```{r,echo=FALSE}
symbolList <- read.csv('symbolList.csv',stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE) #this is what I want to be global

checkFun <- function()
  {
    Sys.time()
  }
valueFun <- function()
  {
    Sys.time()
  }
today <- reactivePoll(5000,NULL, checkFun, valueFun) #only set to 5000ms for testing FYI
valueFun2 <- function()
  {
    sample(1:nrow(symbolList),1)
  }
rand <- reactivePoll(5000,NULL,checkFun,valueFun2)

todayThing <- reactive({symbolList[rand(),1]})
renderPrint({todayThing()})
#...go on to do more things with todayThing
```
#Title and such
````

How can I make the program work so that once per day it will access symbolList and pull a new random item, regenerate the rest of the page (which I can do), and then stay static (and exactly alike) for all users until the next day? I know this is most likely all done server-side, but I just can't piece it together.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, using the `Sys.Date()` and `set.seed` to make it the same everyday

```
set.seed(floor(as.numeric(Sys.Date())))
num_rows <- 5000
n <- sample(num_rows, 1)
```

Then take the nth item from your .csv.

#### edit: timed updates

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
    shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
            textOutput("stuff")
        )
    ),
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  
        values <- reactiveValues()
        values$n <- 0
        observe({
            ## Something like: difftime(Sys.Date()+1, Sys.Date(), units="sec")*1000
            ## to update everyday
            invalidateLater(1000, session)  # update n every second
            isolate( values$n <- values$n + 1 )
        })
        output$stuff <- renderPrint({
            sprintf("Stuff is %s", values$n)
        })
    })
)
```

Comment: That's not a bad idea for making sure the items are the same for each user. Along with your answer, I've answered my own question. I should be able to just stick the read.csv line inside a function that only runs when the date changes, then the list will only get accessed once per day I hope (and not each time the page is loaded)

Comment: It sounds like you are set, but perhaps `invalidateLater` or `reactiveTimer` would be helpful.  I'll add a short example anyway.

Comment: I was planning on using reactivePoll as shown in my example. I changed the `valueFun` to include the initial code you provided so that it now returns the random item from the list, and I changed the `checkFun` to look at the `Sys.Date()` rather than the time. It looks like it is working so far!